# How to restore local PostgreSQL database backup to Azure PostgreSQL server?

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

I have a question of how we can restore a local database backup in Azure PostgreSQL server?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can access your database from the computer you are restoring the DB dump

```bash
pg_restore --dbname=postgresql://user:password@host:port/database_name ./path/to/your/dump.tar.gz
```

Comment: Can't we use direct restore by accessing the Azure postgres Sql server from pgAdmin ?

Comment: You can give it a try. I have not used pgAdmin before.